# Algorithms for computing "optimal set growth order"

Tags: algorithms, sets

Imagine you have a collection of possible "components" (`C`) and a set of "recipes" assembled from those components (`R`).

For example:

```
C = { 'screws', 'bolts', '2x4 pine', 'nuts', ... }
R = {
  { 'screws', '2x4 pine' }, // Shelf
  { 'bolts', 'nuts', '2x4 pine' }, // Pergola
  ...
}
```

Now let's say we have a "toolbox" (`T`) which is just an arbitrary subset of `C`. The "closure" of the toolbox is the subset of recipes that can be made from `T`.

The algorithm I'm curious about is one for figuring out the optimal order in which to acquire components so as to most quickly maximize the recipes that can be built. So for example, if most recipes require screws, we'd expect this "sort" to put screws early on in the acquisition order because it most quickly maximizes the number of recipes in the closure.

I'm actually curious about it in the context of learning Chinese characters and words, but the idea can extend to example sentences in any language and various other domains, so I'm wondering if the problem has already been studied and algorithms developed for it.

The idea seems extensible to arbitrary objective functions over the closure (e.g., being able to build a TV is more valuable than being able to build a USB charger) or multisets where we can track number of each component needed.

Comment: What is the objective function / metric you will use to measure what is optimal?  What is meant by "most quickly maximizes the number of recipes"?  I don't understand how to compare two different candidate orders -- that part sounds rather vague in your problem statement, and we'll need that to be precisely formulated before we can solve it.  The usual way is to define an objective function, which associates a number to each candidate order, and then ask how to maximize this objective function.

Comment: I'm not actually sure! Are there established measures of speed of growth? Intuitively it seems like getting an early jump is more valuable than a late jump, but if then growth tapers off because we got stuck in a local maximum then that seems less appealing. I could imagine some sort of measure that penalizes closure size based on inverse "time" elapsed. The biggest driver behind my question is just that the naive approach here (regardless of objective function) gets me at least `O(n!)` / exponential work, which I'd rather avoid :)

Comment: We can't design the objective function for you because we don't know what your goals are.  One possible goal would be to set a fixed constant $t$ and ask to maximize the number of recipes that are finished by time $t$.  I think you're going to need to spend some time introspecting how you'll use solutions and what measures the quality of a solution.  That's not something we can do for you or answer for you, because it depends on context that only you will know.

Comment: This isn't really trying to solve a specific problem. I have a vague interest in growing character sets for learning but the broader problem of growing sets in ways that maximize an arbitrary objective function still seemed interesting in the abstract, which is why I generalized the statement above. Do you think a hypothetical solution would differ greatly based on the objective function? The subset searching aspects of the problem seem like they'd arise regardless of the objective function, and if the answer is just to throw a general optimization framework at it, I suppose I can do that.